# Creating a browse button with PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a browse button with pyqt5, but I do not get it

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtCore, QtGui

import test3 

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = test3.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.getfiles)


    def getfiles(self):
        fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Single File','C:\'','*.xlsm')
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(fileName)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What **do** you get?

Comment: try with my solution :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code there are 2 errors:

1. `QFileDialog` belongs to `QtWidgets`
2. The second is that the `getOpenFileName` function returns a tuple: `(filename, filter)`, the first element is the filename, and the second is the filter.

For which functions you must change:

```
fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Single File','C:\'','*.xlsm')
```

to:

```
fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Single File', QtCore.QDir.rootPath() , '*.xlsm')
```

Comment: hi
I'm also trying the same but getting an error
code:-
self.pushButton_browse.clicked.connect(self.browsefiles)#

    def browsefiles(self):
        fname=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',QtCore.QDir.rootPath(), 'Images (*.png, *.xmp *.jpg)')
        self.lineEdit_file_loc.setText(fname[0])

Comment: error:-
error:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/thota/OneDrive/Desktop/VET/OVE.py", line 195, in browsefiles
    fname=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',QtCore.QDir.rootPath(), 'Images (*.png, *.xmp *.jpg)')#
TypeError: getOpenFileName(parent: QWidget = None, caption: str = '', directory: str = '', filter: str = '', initialFilter: str = '', options: Union[QFileDialog.Options, QFileDialog.Option] = 0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_Form'

Comment: @Education4Fun Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544780/qtdesigner-changes-will-be-lost-after-redesign-user-interface

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Single File', '', '*.xlsm')